# Deleting Row with multiple WHERE in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, delete-row

Is this the correct way to delete rows with Multiple WHERE arguments? I am trying to make it as safe as I can to the database query.

```
db.delete(TABLE, NAME + "=? and " + ID + "=? and " + ARG3 + "=?", new String[] { myName, x, argument3 });
```

Also is it okay that ID is a integer? Can I still use it inside `String[]` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method looks fine.

---

> Also is it okay that ID is a integer? Can I still use it inside String[] for this?

Your compiler is the best way to answer this question.

However, if `x` (for instance) is an Integer you can use either of these:

```
new String[] { x + "" };
new String[] { String.valueOf(x) };
```

If you are concern that `ID` in `"=? and " + ID + "=? and "` will give you an error, don't worry it won't.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to get this class to compile on eclipse by itself so I am trying to figure that out.